# Separating numbers using %

Tags: java, division, digits

I am trying to get 3 numbers separated by a space after user's input. I can get the first number and the last one dividing by 10, but I really have no idea how to get the middle number

I tried to take the remainder of the first two numbers and then divide them by ten, but IDEA says that the answer is always zero

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Input the number");
    int number = read.nextInt();
    int a = number%10;
    int b = (number%10)/10; // the answer is always 0
    int c = number / 100;
    System.out.println(c + " " + b + " " + a);
}
```

Comment: So for example if you enter `123`, what is `a` going to be? And since `b = a / 10`, why would `b` be anything other than `0` (it's an `int` division!)?

Answer (score 2):

Anything modulo 10 will return a result in the range of 0 to 9, and (integer) dividing that by 10 will return 0. You need to reverse the order - first divide the 10 to remove the last digit, and then take the remainder from 10 to keep the middle digit:

```java
int b = (number / 10) % 10;
```

Comment: That is helpful. Thanks a lot, I got the idea

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using this instead of %. Because you can split and get any digit of number using this code:

```
  int x=158;
  char[] xValueInString = Integer.toString(x).toCharArray();
  for(int i=0; i<xValueInString.length; i++){
      System.out.println(xValueInString[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Actually I haven't got so far in Java, but thanks, I suppose I need to read more info about this statment

Comment: Yeah you can execute it and see the result. I hope you know how to convert String or char to int. I would happy if my post helped you. So please upvote or accept:)

Answer (score -1):

You missed scanner in your code, add Scanner before reading number, try this with little change

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Input the number");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = read.nextInt();
        int a = number%10;
        int b = (number/10)%10; // the answer is always 0
        int c = number/100;
        System.out.println(c + " " + b + " " + a);
    }
```

Comment: It's been there, in Main class, I just shared only method, not the whole class

Comment: I also changed logic for getting number a, b and c. It's working for me.